# How does Executor(max_workers=n).submit() work in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

Running the code below, I noticed that `executor.submit(printer, i)` is called for each value of `i` in `range(100)` before even the first process finishes. However, since I have set `max_workers=3`, only three processes can run at a time. Say the program starts and processes for values zero through two are running; at this moment, what happens to the `executor.submit(printer, i)` called for values three through ninety-nine? And if the answer is "they're stored in memory", is there a way I can calculate how much memory each pending process might take?

```py
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def printer(i):
    print(i)
    end_time = time.time() + 1
    while time.time() < end_time:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        for i in range(100):
            print(i)
            executor.submit(printer, i)
```

Also, would it be the same if I were to use `executor.map(printer, range(100))` instead of the loop?

Comment: There aren't any "pending processes" for submitted tasks. The only thing that is stored is literally ``(printer, i)``; the processes handle several tasks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If a task is submitted but it can't run because of the `max_workers` limitation, wouldn't it be pending? What does it mean to store `(printer, i)`? And could you please elaborate on "the processes handle several tasks"?

Comment: A pending *task* is something else than a pending *process*. The former is just a bunch of metadata and thus takes up mich less memory than the latter.

Comment: I see, so there aren't any "pending processes", as I mentioned in my question, but pending tasks, is what you mean?